# NServiceBus - Aggregate Root - Saga - Synchronous Command

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, nservicebus

Having an aggregate root `User` modeled as NServiceBus Saga

`User.cs`

```
public class User {
   ....
   public string Rename(string name) {
     .// some validation logic
   }
   ...
}
```

`UserSagaData.cs`

```
public class UserSagaData : ContainSagaData
{
  public User User { get; set;}
}
```

`UserSaga.cs`

```
public partial class UserSaga : Saga<RenameUser>
{
   ...
   public async Task Handle(RenameUserimportAttendees, IMessageHandlerContext context)
  {
     Data.User.rename(...
  } 
   ...
}
```

Now i have a requirement to accept RenameUser command via REST API and give the feedback in HTTP Response, hence sending `RegisterUser` to message broker from Controller.Action is not an option. I need to perform command synchronously, get feedback and send http response.

First thing that came to mind is to use `ISagaPersister`, that is, retrieve saga by id, then invoke a command and then persist saga back to the datastore with `ISagaPersister` (which takes care of optimistic locking). Any thoughts on that ?

Is there alternative solutions to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

What type of feedback would you expect the RenameUser command to result in?

Can’t you just return a HTTP OK and queue up the rename command? (assuming that you have validation of the new name in place the chances of something going wrong should be slim and could be dealt with offline should the command end up in the error queue?)

An option if you really have to wait for the response is to use our callbacks package, https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/callbacks, to enable your REST API block until the response has arrived, this way you can still using messaging behind the scenes.

What do you think?

Comment: Well, RenameUser is a example meant to demonstrate an issue, in real scenario there is a high chance of command being rejected and you cannot ensure it will pass without reached the command handler service (It's not simply `Name is not null` but more on the line of `Item has enough timeslots to reserve`)

Comment: Yeah, callbacks seem like a synchronous communication made with asynchronous mechanism which brings the cons of the both (async and sync) communication. On the one hand you have temporal coupling and on another you make much more Network call to bring message to and back from service.